# How to avoid pending requests to fail after database rollback in integration tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, minitest

We have been experiencing an intermittent issue and I would like to see if someone in here has insight to how we can tackle it.
We are doing our integration tests with Minitest + Capybara and Chrome headless driver.

The issue happens when a test has finished and the database gets ROLLBACK'd. There can still be some unfinished requests running in the background, and crashes may occur (like a RecordNotFound) if they try to access unavailable database information.

That kind of problem most commonly happens because of AJAX requests, and for this, we are already using a **wait_for_ajax** helper (that we developed ourselves) to wait until the Browser has finished with his requests.

The unresolved problem happens with `<img>` HTML tags because the browser can still be trying to load images asynchronously even though the tests are finished.

Here is a code example that would cause the issue almost all of the time:

```
test 'image popup should contain some class' do
  upload_some_images # Uploads images
  visit '/list_of_images' # Some page with list of images, you can click on the image and it opens it in a popup

  find('.image-popup-open-button').click # Open image in a popup window
  assert_selector '.some-class-must-be-present'
end
```

This is a simple test, yet, it will always crash in our case with a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound blob id=xxx` error.

- When opening the popup window, an `<img src='/files/123' />` is added to the DOM. The Browser then queries that and gets redirected to the ActiveRecord representation URL.
- The integration test is quite simple and validates if some class is present, then the test is finished and the database is ROLLBACK'd.
- The request for `/files/123` is still running, which then tries to load a blob (database record) that does not exist anymore, and result in an unexpected test failure.

Does anyone ever had such a problem, if so, how did you manage to avoid it?

We are using Ruby 2.5.0, Rails 5.2.2, Capybara 3.0.3

Thank you

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? Are you using database cleaner? What version of Capybara? Have you overridden the Capybara default session reset behavior? Are you letting Capybara manage running the application under test, or have you disabled that? Current Capybaras default setup should wait for all requests to complete when resetting the session unless you've disabled that by trying to do custom things.

Comment: Ok -- You're running Rails 5.2.2 so you shouldn't be using database_cleaner since Rails handles that from Rails 5.1+ - Are these Rails system tests you're writing?  If so do you happen to have written `teardown` blocks where you forgot to call `super`? If so that would prevent Capybaras `reset_sessions!` from being called which is where Capybara waits for all current requests to end before moving on.  If you're not using system tests do you have your own `teardown` block that calls `Capybara.reset_sessions!` at the end of the test?  Also, Capybara 3.0.3 is obsolete nowadays

Comment: Hi @ThomasWalpole, I updated the question with gem versions, thanks for reminding me to put those. We are not using any Database Cleaner gem, we are using rails fixtures. For the session behavior, we have implemented something like [this documentation](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-capybara-with-minitest), though I noticed we have overridden `def after_teardown` and not `def teardown`, not sure if it would change much. Your question "letting Capybara manage running application under test", I am not sure what you are referring to, sorry.

Comment: `after_teardown` vs `teardown` would make a huge difference if the DB is being rolled back during `teardown` - `Capybara.reset_sessions!` needs to be called before the DB is rolled back (I don't remember offhand during which stage Rails rolls back in integration tests - but system tests specifically call reset_sessions from teardown not after_teardown so I assume it should be in `teardown` - try it and see) This all assumes you are letting Capybara run the app (you haven't set Capybara.run_server = false, and then set `app_host` to another instance of the app you are managing startup for)

Comment: Well! @ThomasWalpole You are my man! It was indeed `teardown` vs `after_teardown`. Rails most certainly does rollback in `after_teardown` because after moving the `super` call after `Capybara.reset_sessions!`, it worked. Thanks for pointing me in the right directions, my knowledge of Capybara is still limited so I wasn't able to pinpoint when/where things happens.

Comment: Added as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Capybara is managing the running of the app being tested, `Capybara.reset_sessions!` will wait for all open requests to complete.  This needs to happen before the DB is rolled back. If using Rails system tests this will be handled in a `teardown` block as long as you call `super` from any `teardown` blocks you have defined. If not using system tests and just basing your tests off IntegerationTests you need to define a `teardown` block that calls `Capybara.reset_sessions!` in order to have it wait for all the requests to complete before Rails rolls back the DB.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out we had implemented Capybara this way:

```
def after_teardown
  super
  Capybara.reset_sessions!
  Capybara.use_default_driver
end
```

but Rails rollbacks the database in the `super` call of `after_teardown`. So the database was rollbacked before Capybara waits for the session to finish.

Moving the `super` after `Capybara.reset_sessions!` did the trick (it also makes sense to put it inside `def teardown` instead, which is most probably what we will do).

Thank you to @ThomasWalpole for pointing me in the right direction.